# Flask-Markdown / Flask-Misaka filter wrapping Markdown in pre tag

Tags: python, flask, markdown

I'm having an issue getting markdown to work with my Flask app. I have imported the markdown extension via pip. I'm having an issue where the jinja2 {% filter markdown %} is acting weird. It is wrapping my markdown in pre tags. However if I pass md text straight to the template {{ '#text' | markdown}} it will parse the string correctly. I'm guessing that the markdown filter is not being passed to Jinja but I don't know how to eval or troubleshoot this. Has anyone else run into this?

FLASK

```
from flask_mikasa import Mikasa
app = Flask(__name__)
Misaka(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    index_content = Index().get(Index.active == 1)
    return render_template('index.html',  index_content=index_content)
```

MD IN INDEX.HTML

```
{% filter markdown %}
        <h1>Page for: {{ name }}</h1>

        ![Company Logo][logo]
        # {{ index_content.main_title }}
        {{ index_content.main_text }}

        ## {{ index_content.column1_title }}
        {{ index_content.column1_text }}
        [Read More](http://google.com)

        ## {{ index_content.column2_title }}
        {{ index_content.column2_text }}
        [Read More](http://google.com)

        ## {{ index_content.column3_title }}
        {{ index_content.column3_text }}
        [Read More](http://google.com)

        [logo]:{{ url_for('static', filename='logo.jpg')}}
{% endfilter %}
```

OUTPUT:

```
html: opening_pre_tag
html: opening_code_tag
&lt;h1&gt;Page for: &lt;/h1&gt;

    ![Company Logo][logo]
    # Header


    ## Content Title 1
    Lorem Ipsum
    [Read More](http://google.com)

    ## Content Title 2
    lorem ipsum
    [Read More](http://google.com)

    ## Content Title 3
    Lorem ipsum... 
    [Read More](http://google.com)

    [logo]:/static/logo.jpg
html: closing_code_tag
html: closing_pre_tag
```

HOWEVER

```
{{ '#title' | markdown }}
```

will output

```
<h1>title</h1>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so the {% filter markdown %} needs to be in the same tab line as the markdown content. Easy fix but frustrating process.

i.e.

```
{% filter markdown %}
# Title
content
List: 
* a
* b
* c
{% endfilter %)
```

vs.

```
{% filter markdown %}
    # Title
    content
    List: 
    * a
    * b
    * c
{% endfilter %}
```

Comment: Indenting formats the text as code/preformatted as per markdown specification. It just must not be indented